# Can .net 8 Authentication api system be used in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I followed this video by Nick Chapsas.  He cut a few corners for brevity (e.g. installing EF toolkit etc.), but it was pretty easy to get things going.  I was very happy how the api worked, and with the JSON values returned.

But my first case would be this: a Blazor (not scaffolded Area/Identity/Login) page with username and password inputs.  I send the info to the API, I get back a token, and. . . and what?  Can we actually do this now?  How would I actually use this in a Blazor server app / hybrid web app?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZnu-TyaGNk